# OutOfMemory - Native thread creation failure

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, native

before you read this let me tell you that please don't reply that this is repeated or check this link or the other. I know and I have checked many links and suggestions but still need you look at this as well. making the story short:

ENV:
java 32 bit 1.6 update 38
jboss 5.1. GA
RAM on server 8 GB
JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx1024M

study case:
 the load of the server (web service calls) increased and we started to see this since then.

server log shows below exception:
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

and also sometimes:
2014-10-03 10:33:45,200 ERROR [STDERR] (AWT-Windows) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError

OBSERVATIONS DURING LAST THREE DAYS:

OS memory performance monitoring:
the commit memory is increasing slowly

jvisualvm data:
no heap space issue observed, GC doing its job properly so I dont see any leak there.
thread dump shows many WAIT threads! 
I tracked our application packages in the heap dump and did not find any big issue (still investigating) however I think we are not managing the threads properly.

number of threads after jboss restart increases form 50 to 260 threads and never decreases even on idle situation when there is no activity on the server. it seems strange to me.

heap usage is up to 400 MB which is way lesser than max 1024 MV

Now I hope, really hope someone can guide me through this and help me to resolve it. what I think is that the stack is small? or our application is not handling threads properly.

could you kindly help me?
thanks.

Comment: How many threads have you created?

Comment: I got as far as 'before you read this let me tell you that please don't reply' and then stopped as you aparrently don't want an answer.

Comment: don't get me wrong :) and don't interpret it badly please. I do want answers but I wanted to mention that I have seen many pages and I have googled a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This seems you are creating enormous threads and there by exceeded thread limits (in short you's process might be lacking native memory to create additional threads). Please see http://java.dzone.com/articles/outofmemoryerror-unable-create for more details.

Comment: I did look at it before, and I believe my case is the third scenario but still I need some solution to this. is it somewhere in my code? or I can still play with the env varibles? like heap size, stack size and if yes, where ? and which file...

Comment: Is it on Unix/Windows? Also is it reproduceable?

Comment: Win server 08 yes it is reproducible but only on prod env i could never make it on test env. 260 is not too much but i have many waiting threadsqnd also why it never reduces...

Comment: One important piece of info. We are running three instances under ine jboss.

Comment: Didnt get that? Can you please update the question as it will be helpful to others as well. Please include as much information as you can.